# Can is_lock_free() return true for some data types and false for another one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, atomic

I know that `is_lock_free` depends on the hardware but when I used it on an ADT it returned false but true with `int` type. How this can be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
struct myType {

    size_t ID{};
    size_t to{};
};
int main() {


    std::atomic<myType> i{ };
    std::cout << "\n" << i.is_lock_free();

    std::atomic j { 1};
    std::cout << "\n" << j.is_lock_free();

}
```

Comment: Probably because processors have optimized instructions to perform load/stores in a single instruction for `int` which means you don't need a lock? Atomic data types guarantee it will be done "atomically" but not necessarily in a single instruction, therefore using a lock or other locking primitive internally.

Comment: It appears that your processor is capable of performing atomic operations on int-sized memory values, but not on `2 * sizeof(size_t)`-sized memory values. This is not unreasonable. There's going to a point where the processor can't operate atomically any more. It's not like you can reasonably expect to be able to perform an atomic write to a 1GB block of memory.

Comment: @RaymondChen So that depends on the hardware only. Does that mean my processor (core i 7 - 9750 H) is poor?

Comment: @asmmo No, it makes it normal :-)

Comment: That can also depend on the compiler, and if the library it uses supports the larger atomics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can is_lock_free() return true for some data types and false for another one?

Yes, it can. It is possible for the shown program to output 0 1.

In fact, if this wasn't the case, then there would be no point for the function to be a member of a template.